# I cannot create Facebook apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

When I try to create a new app I receive the message

> Only verified developers can be added as listed developers of this application. Read http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=17580 for details.

However, **I am a verified user**. I both gave Facebook my credit card details and phone number. And in fact, when I follow the links, I receive the message "your mobile phone has been successfully verified".

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: When did you add your phone number & credit card? Sometimes it takes time. I would give it 3 business days.

Comment: @Xarcell Months ago. :(